# Magento 2 How to get/group orders by shipping addresses

Tags: magento2, orders, shipping-address, magento2.2.2

Seems like Magento doesn't have a way to get all orders by shipping addresses. This is obviously because of the following:

1. Magento doesn't store addresses as unique entities, this means every time there is an order, Magento will create a new entity for that address even if already exists and is exactly the same.
2. Because its a new entity, every time an order is placed it will have its unique `entity_id` which is then stored against the `sales_order` table under the `shipping_address_id` column. This means we will not be able to easily check how many orders have been done under a specific address because they all have different `entity_id` (unique keys).

So has anyone every come across this before or can you think of a way of achieve this?

EDIT:

**Here is some context why I need this.**

We basically want a way to flag addresses as trusted if it has x amount of non-refunded orders between z timeframe. When a customer checks out the input address will be lookup on a table with trusted addresses if it is found then it is sent to our fraud system to do extra validations with the address set as trusted.

Comment: load all order addresses and use a foreach loop to compare them, maybe?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer hmm not really an efficient way. I'll add a proper description when I get time, so it makes more sense.

Comment: @simonthesorcerer I say its not an efficient way because when you have millions or orders that can really degrade the site performance.

Comment: yes, it didn't sound to me like you would want to do it regularly on the fly. can you maybe add the business use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So done some research, this is obviously going to take a loot of resources and time to do on the fly. Here is my current approach to this issue which seems to work pretty well.

Because we can't really get orders by addresses in a easy way, every time an order is place a new entry is added for the address being used under `sales_order_address`. I came up with this query which concatenates the `street`, `city` and `country` of the `sales_order_address` and then groups all other matching addresses which doing a JOIN to the `sales_order` table to check if the `entity_id` of the `sales_order` table record matches the `parent_id` of the `sales_order_address` table.

```
SELECT
     CONCAT(order_addresses.`street`, order_addresses.`city`, order_addresses.`country_id`) AS address,
     COUNT(*) AS 'order_count'
     FROM `sales_order_address` AS `order_addresses`
         LEFT JOIN `sales_order` AS `sales` ON sales.`entity_id` = order_addresses.`parent_id`
             WHERE order_addresses.`address_type` = "shipping"
                 AND sales.`base_total_refunded` IS NULL
                 AND sales.`status` = "complete"
                 AND sales.`state` = "complete"
                 AND DATE(sales.`created_at`) >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL [THIS_IS_A_SYSTEM_VALUE] MONTH)
     GROUP BY address
     HAVING order_count > [THIS_IS_A_SYSTEM_VALUE]
```

The above query will be run occasionally every month and once a customer places an order there will be an observer which will look up into a temporary table which was created from the above SELECT and then if the address is trusted it will sent the required information to our fraud system.

[Here](https://github.com/ferrazzuk/magento2-mysql-scripts) is a link to my git repo where I will be posting useful SQL queries for Magento 2.